# How to remove the warning '~~without onChange handler.' while using checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am doing react js.

I got annoying warning when I am using input checkbox.

The waring message is like below.

[image]

On input checkbox tag, I used `checked` prop and used `onClick` handler instead of `onChange` handler.

I think it seems no problem.

Can I just ignore this warning message? or am I missing something?

Thank you for any comment about this.

Comment: 1. Show us your actual relevant code, 2. Why are you using `onClick` instead of `onChange`? Keyboard users should still be able to fill out your form without having to get a mouse to click on the checkbox

Comment: @Samathingamajig I got it.. I should use onChange for keyboard user..

Comment: You should just use `onChange`. `onChange` works for both keyboard AND mouse users, and also a few other input methods, while `onClick` only works with mouse (and calling `element.click()`), so React tells you that you're making a mistake when you use `onClick`

Comment: @Samathingamajig yeah..! I totally understood. 
thank you :) !

Answer (score 0):

The warning message has pretty much explained what is going on. The question is why do you `checked` and `onClick` instead of `onChange`.